# How to determine range of wires that can safety fit into wire nut?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have the following pack of wire nuts:
[image]

On the back of the package is information on the types of wire combinations it can be used with:
[image]

The range is also specified at https://ecat.eleknet.com/PIM_Docs/Docs/STEP_ASSETS_PDF/13049461.pdf:
[image]

How do I interpret these ranges? I can understand if it says min. (2) x #16, max (4) x #16. This means I can have 2 to 4  16 AWG wires in the nut. But when different wire gauges and types are mixed into the range, I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: the top of chart shows wire size and count ... it says min 4 wires, 2 #16 and 2 #18

Comment: @jsotola, what about 2 #14? What about 2 #12 or 3 #12? The chart doesn't address those even though they are likely to be *the most common use*. I agree that the chart is at minimum confusing, or maybe outright lame... or perhaps there is some esoteric secret knowledge that make mystical electricians able to interpret...

Comment: I was thinking that, in which case it's more of a list of wire groupings than a range. Since it's drawn as a line, I was thinking electricians somehow intuit the values between the column tracks. I guess not, thanks!

Comment: looking at the chart again ... i see an inconsistency at 1#14w/4#12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not wrong.  While Ideal makes great wire nuts, I have to agree those graphs are just junk.  It's not really information that lends itself to a bar graph.

This document is available for US models and gives you the exact info you need:

https://www.idealind.com/content/dam/electrical/assets/WireTermination/WireConnectors/TwistOn/WireNut/UL%20ListedWireCombinations.pdf

Other brands have similar reference materials.  Here is the section for the US equivalent, model 76B:

[image: Ideal76B]

That's more like it, right?  But it's a lot to put on a label.

The picture in the question is a Canadian version of the wire nut (or would that be a marrette?) and I can't find an equivalent document for their Canadian product numbers.  Ideal's web site was updated a while ago and is half useless.

Comment: That _is_ a lot to put on a label, but on a label it is on all three boxen of wire nuts I have in the garage. I've had 'em there long enough that I could read it easily when I bought 'em and now need my "old man" glasses to make it out.

Comment: That document is annoying.  The wire nuts are color-coded, but they don't even bother listing colors?

Comment: Also, that document says things like "1 #8 w/1 or 3 #16".  Am I supposed to interpret "1 or 3" to mean "1 through 3", or does it mean 1 #8 w/2 #16" is somehow not an acceptable combination?